# Change layout of table columns

Tags: tables, columns, layout

I created this table, but I am not happy with the layout. The column "Musical" is too much to the right. Is there a way to have the columns "Oper", "Operette" and "Musical" in more equal big columns? Can you follow me? Would be great to find a solution for that. Thank you.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\noalign{%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.1pt}%
\let\noalign\empty
\hline
}%
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CAGR der Veranstaltungsentwicklung in \%}}  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} \textbf{Theater} & \textbf{Oper} & \textbf{Operette} & \textbf{Musical} \\ 
\hline
Staatstheater & -1,15 & -3,16 & 5,55 \\
Landestheater & -1,21 & -5,45 & -1,66 \\
Stadttheater & -1,71 & -2,48 & -3,09 \\
fusionierte Theater & -1,90 & -3,86 & -1,28 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018]{Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018}
\label{tab:entwickl_veranstaltung_alle_Theater}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: There remains a problem: the minus signs are actually hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}

With \verb!hspan=even! option:

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {lccc},
  row{1-2} = {gray9,font=\bfseries},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c}, % multicolumn
  hspan = even, % distribute extra space evenly
}
\hline[1.1pt]
                      & CAGR der Veranstaltungsentwicklung in \% & &  \\
  Theater             & Oper  & Operette & Musical \\ 
\hline
  Staatstheater       & -1,15 & -3,16    &  5,55   \\
  Landestheater       & -1,21 & -5,45    & -1,66   \\
  Stadttheater        & -1,71 & -2,48    & -3,09   \\
  fusionierte Theater & -1,90 & -3,86    & -1,28   \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\caption[Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018]{Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018}
\label{tab:entwickl_veranstaltung_alle_Theater}
\end{table}

With \verb!hspan=even! option and \verb!siunitx! library:

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {l*{3}{S[table-format=-1.2]}},
  row{1-2} = {gray9,font=\bfseries},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c}, % multicolumn
  hspan = even, % distribute extra space evenly
}
\hline[1.1pt]
                      & {{{CAGR der Veranstaltungsentwicklung in \%}}} & & \\
  Theater             & {{{Oper}}}  & {{{Operette}}} & {{{Musical}}} \\ 
\hline
  Staatstheater       & -1,15 & -3,16    &  5,55   \\
  Landestheater       & -1,21 & -5,45    & -1,66   \\
  Stadttheater        & -1,71 & -2,48    & -3,09   \\
  fusionierte Theater & -1,90 & -3,86    & -1,28   \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\caption[Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018]{Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018}
\label{tab:entwickl_veranstaltung_alle_Theater}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `\makecell` directive to line-break the long header.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2]} }
\noalign{%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.1pt}%
\let\noalign\empty
\hline
}%
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries \makecell{CAGR der Veranstaltungs-\\entwicklung, in \%}}  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}  
\textbf{Theater} & {\textbf{Oper}} & {\textbf{Operette}} & {\textbf{Musical}} \\ 
\hline
Staatstheater & -1,15 & -3,16 & 5,55 \\
Landestheater & -1,21 & -5,45 & -1,66 \\
Stadttheater  & -1,71 & -2,48 & -3,09 \\
fusionierte Theater & -1,90 & -3,86 & -1,28 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018]{Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018}
\label{tab:entwickl_veranstaltung_alle_Theater}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's an idea but I would prefer not to line break the word here

Comment: @Mico: I tend to not use `makecell` with coloured rows, as there are often problems, which disappear with  `stackengine` and its `\Centerstack` command.

Comment: @qu33ristan - If you don't want to line-break the 25-letter/7-syllable word Veranstaltungsentwicklung at the place I chose in my answer, which other line break do you consider to be preferable?

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for pointing out this fact. It would certainly explain why the output of `\cline{2-4}` isn't visibie.

Comment: @Mico: When ordinary rules are not or hardly visible, `\hhline`s are, usually.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the `S` column type, from `siunitx`, for the last three columns and to fix their width. I also took the liberty to change the shade of grey for the first two rows.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{calc} 
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{caption} 
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.2, table-number-alignment=center, copy-decimal-marker, table-column-width=2cm}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
    \caption[Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018]{Entwicklung der Musiktheaterveranstaltungszahlen der Theater der Studie 1 im Zeitraum 2008/2009 bis 2017/2018}
    \label{tab:entwickl_veranstaltung_alle_Theater}
    \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
    \noalign{%
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.1pt}%
    \let\noalign\empty
    \hline
    }%
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textbf{CAGR der Veranstaltungsentwicklung in \%}} \\
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\textbf{Theater} & {\bfseries Oper} & {\bfseries Operette} & {\bfseries Musical} \\
    \hline
    Staatstheater & -1,15 & -3,16 & 5,55 \\
    Landestheater & -1,21 & -5,45 & -1,66 \\
    Stadttheater & -1,71 & -2,48 & -3,09 \\
    fusionierte Theater & -1,90 & -3,86 & -1,28 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that works but it's a complete different layout than I am using...

Comment: I answered your requirement: the last three columns have the same width. The only things I changed are the row colors (it's easy to revert  to your own color if you prefer – it is only a suggestion), and using a `\multicolumn{4}{r}{…} ` in the first row to avoid  problems with the \rowcolor.

Answer (score 0):

I helped myself now with

```
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ l  C{2.1cm}  C{2.1cm}  C{2.1cm} }

...
```

Comment: Since line-breaking in the three data columns is neither advisable nor needed, defining the `L`, `C`, and `R` column types may be a bit of overkill. You could write, more simply, `\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{ w{c}{2.1cm} } }`.